# Azure DevOps Construct Naming Convention

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

Do we have an official, Microsoft defined naming convention for Azure DevOps Pipeline [concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops), [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch), [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) and any other constructs?

Encountered [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/naming-restrictions?view=azure-devops) documentation which only defines naming restrictions for high level concepts such as, projects and not aforementioned constructs.

Please advise us on the approach to follow, if there is such a naming convention.

Comment: are you looking for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/naming-restrictions?view=azure-devops

Comment: @Sajeetharan that documentation does not provide a comprehensive guide of the Pipeline constructs. Appreciate if we can look into the constructs defined above and in the issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/10481.

Answer (score 2):

I think most of the naming restrictions mentioned in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/naming-restrictions?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) should be also available to Azure Pipelines, although it does not specially mention Azure Pipelines.

I have reported an issue ([MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs#10481](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/10481)) to the appropriate document team, and hope them can update the document to add the naming restrictions for Azure Pipelines in the document.

You can follow this issue ticket and add your comments to it.